# How can I set this variable(number) to percent?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have div(box2) which has 0 width.

```
<div class="box">  
    <div class="box2"></div>     
</div>
```

I would like to set its width in percent with javascript/jQuery. Since I have that function below:

```
var a = 50;
var b = 100;
function percentage(x,y){
    return a * 100 / b;
}
var box2Width = percentage(a,b);
$('.box2').animate({
    width: box2Width
},400);
```

I get the percentage of box2 width(50) but in numbers as you can see.. How can I convert this in percent so that box2 can get 50% percent width?

Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/Rd9rE/

Thanx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing **a** and **b** in percentage instead of parameter passed, change it otherwise it would cause unexpected result later.

Or Return with percentage sign from function [Here is Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Rd9rE/4/):

```
function percentage(x, y) {
    return (x * 100 / y)+'%';
}

$('.box2').animate({
    width: percentage(50, 100) 
}, 400);
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to append the `%` symbol to the value:

```
width: box2Width + '%'
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Rd9rE/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Just add the `%`

```
$('.box2').animate({
    width: box2Width + '%'
},400);
```

Answer (score 0):

as you are getting the percentage value by function

```
var box2Width = percentage(a,b);
```

You just need a `%` sign at the end of the value,so just add `%` any where in the result or function

```
 $('.box2').animate({
        width: box2Width+'%'
    },400);
```

OR

```
function percentage(x,y){
    return (a * 100 / b)+'%';
}
```